# How to sort using key function which takes more than one argument?

Tags: python, function, sorting

I have a list of positions in a game board, i.e., each position is represented by a tuple: (row, column)

I wish to sort the list from the most centric position in the board, to the most outer position.

So I used `positionsList.sort(key=howCentric)`, while `howCentric` returns an integer which represents how centric the received position is.
the problem is that I would like howCentric function to receive 2 arguments: a position tuple, and the board's side length: `def howCentric(position, boardSideLength)`.

Is it possible for the key function to receive more than one argument?

(I wouldn't like to use a global variable because it is considered a bad habit, and obviously I wouldn't like to create a position tuple which contains also the board's side length, i.e., `position = (row, column, boardSideLength)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lambda`s work here:

```
positionsList.sort(key=lambda p: howCentric(p, boardLength))
```

Answer (score 1):

The key function passed to the `sort` method must accept one and only one argument -- the items in `positionList`. However, you could use a function factory so `howCentric` can access the value of `boardSideLength`:

```
def make_howCentric(boardSideLength):
    def howCentric(position):
        ...
    return howCentric

positionsList.sort(key=make_howCentric(boardSideLength))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def howCentric(boardSideLength, position):
    #position contains the items passed from positionsList
    #boardSideLength is the fixed argument.
    ...

positionsList.sort(key=partial(howCentric, boardSideLength))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `Board` is a class, you can make `side_length` an instance attribute and use that in the sort function:

```
class Board(object):

    def __init__(self, side_length, ...):
        self.side_length = side_length
        self.positions_list = ...

    def _how_centric(self, pos):
        # use self.side_length and pos

    def position_list_sorted(self):
        return sorted(self.positions_list, key=self._how_centric)
```